# Video uploading and streaming using the samsung note 3 is not working

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-videoview

I am working on an android application. In my application, I am implementing video uploading to the server and also streaming the uploaded video from the server to my mobile in real time like streaming in you tube. I am able to upload and stream videos taken from mobile like micromax, nexus 7 and moto g. But when I tried with samsung devices, though i successfully uploaded the video taken from samsung device, and when I tried to stream it I am getting some error like "IOexception . setdatasource failed". Even the media player wgich is trying to stream the video is displaying the duration of video as 00:00. Please help me. Thanks in advance, Prince